# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Buddhism breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 12          4
Users destroyed                                   5          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Users contacted                                  18          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            99         69
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               11          0
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         62          9
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              101         93
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               339        118
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               30          7
Revisions redacted                                4          0
Questions reopened                               17          0
Questions protected                              37          2
Questions migrated                                6          0
Questions merged                                  3          0
Questions flagged⁴                                5        152
Questions closed                                128          3
Question flags handled⁴                         105         52
Posts unlocked                                    2          4
Posts undeleted                                  18         54
Posts locked                                      6         26
Posts deleted⁵                                  192        308
Posts bumped                                      0        265
Comments undeleted                               78          0
Comments flagged                                  6        416
Comments deleted⁶                             1,780        960
Comment flags handled                           189        233
Answers flagged                                  12        173
Answer flags handled                            173         12
All comments on a post moved to chat             73          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...